# Rails 3.2 generators? What convenience methods exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently reading [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/generators.html)

Is there no way to generate a Rails controller quickly? I am trying to generate two things right now:

1. A rails controller that exists in

> app/controllers/api/recipes/recipe_tools_controller.rb

2. A route that looks like this:

> root/api/recipes/1/tools

Is there a way for me to quickly do this?

Comment: what about: `rails g resource api::recipes:tools` ?